# Composite Chart + Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, charts

I want to implement below chart like structure.
Explanation:
1. Each block should be clickable.
2. If the block is selected, it will be highlighted(i.e. Red block in figure).

I initially google for this but was unable to find. What should be "Drawing logic" corresponding to this with animation?Thanx in advance.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to use `MCSegmentedControl`.

You can get it from [here](https://github.com/oettam/MCSegmentedControl).

Comment: Agree. The OP essentially wants a segmented control with variable sized segments.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, I'd have an image for the outline with a transparent middle, then dynamically create colored blocks behind it of the appropriate colors, with dynamic labels.  The highlighting is a little tricky, but could be done with a set of image overlays.  One could also try to shrink and expand fixed images for the bars/highlighting, but iPhone scales images poorly.

(Will it always be 4 blocks?  There are a couple of other ways to manage it using fixed-size images overlaying each other.)

Comment: Thanx for reply.About blocks can be increased.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should look into using CALayer for this?

Comment: That's like saying, "maybe you should draw it." What help is that?

Comment: @Harkonian Although it's far from a complete answer, I think it's actually a pretty useful hint.

Comment: (And if it were me, I'd rather have a hint in the right direction, than a more fully spelled out solution in the wrong. Just sayin'.)

Answer (score 0):

U need to implement this type of logic using button. Just scale button width according to percentage.

And to make round rect button like appearance use the code below and don't forget to import quartz-core framework in class file.

And to scale first and last button as you need some overlap from nearby button.

```
btn.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0;
btn.layer.borderWidth = 0.5;
btn.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
```